# sudo pip install django-nose: "no such file or directory" followed by an empty string?

Tags: python, permissions, pip, osx-elcapitan

When trying to `sudo pip install django-nose`, I get a strange error:

```
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 549, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 963, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 266, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 176, in clobber
      os.makedirs(dest)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode) 
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

I am only using `sudo` because without sudo, I get a `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/__init__.py'`. Here is what I get for which Python and pip is being used, which I think are both what I want them to be:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

This is a separate issue, but I wonder if it's related: I also get this error while trying to create a virtualenv: `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_install.py'`

I recently upgraded to El Capitan, and it seems like there were some permissions changes that may have caused it to suddenly not work even though it has been working for a while. (Although I'll admit I'm not super experienced here, so I could be doing something very obviously wrong.) I just have no idea how to even decipher this error, and obviously I don't want to do any `chmod` or `chown` on system files unless I absolutely know it will solve my problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!